# XML directly via querying ORACLE db

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, schema

I am querying an Oracle DB, to make XMLs out of each row using XMLELEMENT and XMLFOREST.
For Single table it is working fine. But my requirement is now to fetch data from 3 different tables.

Description:

Table Main, SecondTable, ThirdTable. In which Main and SecondTable has unique TxnIDs while in ThirdTable its repeating.

Example:

```
 Main Table                        SecondTable                      ThirdTable

TxnId  A   B   C             D    TxnId   E    F                  G    H   I   TxnId

1001   3   4   6             5    1001    6    2                  2    5   5    1001
1002   5   6   2             4    1002    5    6                  6    8   9    1001
1003   5   4   2             6    1003    5    6                  8    9   8    1001
```

I want to reperesent these data in XML, so far I am able to get first row in form of XML using,

```
Select XMLELELEMENT(("Event", XMLFOREST(m.A as 'A',
                                        m.B as 'B',
                                        m.C as 'C') ||
                              XMLELEMENT("SecondTable",
                                         XMLFOREST(s.E as 'E',
                                                   s.F as 'F')) ||
                              XMLELEMENT("ThirdTable",
                                         XMLFOREST(t.G as 'G',
                                                   t.H as 'H',
                                                   t.I as 'I')))
  from Main m
  JOIN SecondTable s
    ON m.TxnId=s.TxnId
  JOIN ThirdTable t
    ON s.TxnId=t.TxnId
```

This Query will give me output like--

```
<Event>
   <Main>
      <A>3</A>
      <B>4</B>
      <C>6</C>
   </Main>
  <SecondTable>
      <E>6</E>
      <F>2</F>
  </SecondTable>
       <ThirdTable>
             <G>2</G>
             <H>5</H>
             <I>5</I>
       </ThirdTable>
 </Event>
```

Question: **I want Repeating TxnIds of ThirdTable to form 3 blocks in a single XML.** I hope I am clear.
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can it be done by PL SQL?
Pls guide me somebdy.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an example of the output you want, as well as the output you're getting.

Comment: In addition, the query you posted won't execute - [see this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93201/3). It produces a "missing right parenthesis" error (caused apparently by having two left parens after the first call to XMLELEMENT) - but when that's corrected there's a "missing identifier" error. People here are willing to try and help but you've got to do your part. Please edit your question and include a query which produces the output you've shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xmlagg function along with a group by clause to achieve this. I've also included an outter join to the ThirdTable. Please see my solution below, hope this helps:

scenario set up:

```
            create table main 
            (txnid number(4),a VARCHAR2(1), b VARCHAR2(1), c VARCHAR2(1));

            insert into main values (1001, 3 ,4 ,6);
            insert into main values (1002, 5 ,6 ,2);
            insert into main values (1003, 5 ,4 ,2);

            create table secondtable 
            (d VARCHAR2(1),txnid number(4), e VARCHAR2(1), f VARCHAR2(1));

            insert into secondtable values (5, 1001 ,6 ,2);
            insert into secondtable values (4, 1002 ,5 ,6);
            insert into secondtable values (6, 1003 ,5 ,6);

            create table thirdtable 
            (g VARCHAR2(1), h VARCHAR2(1), i VARCHAR2(1), txnid number(4));


            insert into thirdtable  values (2, 5 ,5 ,1001);
            insert into thirdtable  values (6, 8 ,9 ,1001);
            insert into thirdtable  values (8, 9 ,8 ,1001);

            commit;
```

query:

```
            select XMLELEMENT("Event", xmlelement("Main", 
                                          XMLFOREST(m.A as "A",
                                                    m.B as "B",
                                                    m.C as "C")), 
                                            XMLELEMENT("SecondTable",
                                                       XMLFOREST(s.E as "E",
                                                                 s.F as "F")) ,
                                            xmlagg(XMLELEMENT("ThirdTable",
                                                       XMLFOREST(t.G as "G",
                                                                 t.H as "H",
                                                                 t.I as "I")))) xml_payload
            from main m, secondtable s, thirdtable t
            where m.TxnId=s.TxnId
            and   s.TxnId=t.TxnId(+)
            group by m.txnid, s.txnid, m.a, m.b, m.c, s.e, s.f;
```

alternative, using a sub-select and removing the group by and outter join:

```
            select XMLELEMENT("Event", xmlelement("Main", 
                                                XMLFOREST(m.A as "A",
                                                          m.B as "B",
                                                          m.C as "C")), 
                                                  XMLELEMENT("SecondTable",
                                                             XMLFOREST(s.E as "E",
                                                                       s.F as "F")),                                                        
                                                  (select xmlagg(XMLELEMENT("ThirdTable",
                                                             XMLFOREST(t.G as "G",
                                                                       t.H as "H",
                                                                       t.I as "I")))
                                                    from thirdtable t
                                                    where s.TxnId=t.TxnId
                                                   )) xml_payload
                  from main m, secondtable s
                  where m.TxnId=s.TxnId;
```

to have all the elements in third table repeat under a single  just move the xmlagg down a level:

```
            select XMLELEMENT("Event", xmlelement("Main", 
                                                XMLFOREST(m.A as "A",
                                                          m.B as "B",
                                                          m.C as "C")), 
                                                  XMLELEMENT("SecondTable",
                                                             XMLFOREST(s.E as "E",
                                                                       s.F as "F")),                                                        
                                                  (select XMLELEMENT("ThirdTable",xmlagg(
                                                             XMLFOREST(t.G as "G",
                                                                       t.H as "H",
                                                                       t.I as "I")))
                                                    from thirdtable t
                                                    where s.TxnId=t.TxnId
                                                   )) xml_payload
                  from main m, secondtable s
                  where m.TxnId=s.TxnId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will this query puts repeating TxnIds of thirdTable, to form  three blocks  in a single XML?

Comment: Because in our requirement, we dont know how many times the txnId will be repeating. If it repeats, query should handle by forming required number of blocks. For above example <thirdTable> <G></G><H></H><I></I>   <G></G><H></H><I></I>  <G></G><H></H><I></I></thirdTable>

Comment: My previous example will repeat each row (however many there are for a txnid) in the third table under a <ThirdTable> node. This way you can see which G/H/I belong together - i.e. the XML is nicely formed. However if you really need the G/H/I nodes all repeating under the same <ThirdTable> node please see my modified answer. Hope this helps. J

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. it really helps me alot. Now the issue I am facing.. I have implemented above query for my data which is having 400+ columns and 50k data in both FirstTable and ThirdTable. Query is taking hell lot of time. I am using subquery to fetch this. Any idea to optimize ? Pls help

Comment: Are there foreign keys / indexes between the three tables? Do statistics need rebuilt? Have you had a look at the Explain Plan to see that the query looks ok? Have you tried the version with the sub-select and compared it to the version with the three tables in one main from clause?

Comment: My query is working fine now. But for large amount of data I am not able to export it from SQL developer. Warning message is displaying as "We currently do no support CLOB,BLOB".   How do I save my result set to .xml ?  please provide me your insight if you could. Thanks

Comment: Hi Braine, Do you know what size the xml is? You can find this out using: 

                select dbms_lob.getlength(xmltype.getclobval(<yourxml>)) from dual;

Also have you access to sqlplus, if so its quite easy to just spool the xml to a file. You might need to use this method if the xml is quite large.